# Algorithm for a simple non-locking-on-read concurrent map?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency

I'm trying to write a map that is thread-safe, but never locks or blocks on read.  My attempt is to use a read-only map that gets copied out on write.  The idea is *get()* is lock-free, and *put()* copies the current read-only underlying map to a new one, does the put, and swaps out the current underlying map for a new one.  (yes, *put()* is inefficient since it copies the entire map, but I do not care for my use case)

My first stab at this used std::atomic<*StringMap> for the read-only map **BUT** there is a huge bug with this, probably due to my java background.  *get()* atomically gets a pointer to the underlying map, which may or may not be the current one when it loads it (which is ok).  But *put()* deletes the underlying map after it swaps it out for the new one.  If *get()* is calling the old map just as it gets deleted, this will obviously crash.

A friend of mine suggested **shared_ptr**, but he's not sure if the shared_ptr operations do any locking under the covers.  <strike>The docs say it is thread-safe, though.</strike>  **Edit:** As nosid points out, it is not thread safe and I need the special atomic operation from std::atomic.

So my questions are:   1.  Is this algorithm viable?  2.  Do shared_ptr operations do any locking, especially on access?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <atomic>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <memory>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> StringMap;

class NonBlockingReadMap {
private:
    pthread_mutex_t fMutex;    
    std::shared_ptr<StringMap> fspReadMapReference;


public:

    NonBlockingReadMap() {
        fspReadMapReference = std::make_shared<StringMap>();
    }

    ~NonBlockingReadMap() {
        //so, nothing here?
    }

    std::string get(std::string &key) {
        //does this access trigger any locking?
        return fspReadMapReference->at(key);
    }

    void put(std::string &key, std::string &value) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&fMutex);
        std::shared_ptr<StringMap> spMapCopy = std::make_shared<StringMap>(*fspReadMapReference);
        std::pair<std::string, std::string> kvPair(key, value);
        spMapCopy->insert(kvPair);
        fspReadMapReference.swap(spMapCopy);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fMutex);
    }

    void clear() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&fMutex);
        std::shared_ptr<StringMap> spMapCopy = std::make_shared<StringMap>(*fspReadMapReference);
        fspReadMapReference.swap(spMapCopy);
        spMapCopy->clear();
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fMutex);
    }

};
```

Comment: "is inefficient since it copies the entire map, but I do not care for my use case" -- then are you sure that you need the complexity of a tiered-locking scheme?

Comment: @BrianCain - for my use case, yes.  Several threads will be pounding get() constantly.  put()s will be infrequent (days/weeks apart) after an initial start up bubble.

Comment: There's a port of java's non-blocking hashmap for c++, why not look at that first? If they implemented the underlying FSM correctly you even get correctness proofs for the implementation. And if not at least you have a proven concept to start with.

Comment: @Voo - do you have a link for that?  I googled, but besides Intel TBB, I didn't see anything as you describe.  Seems like it would be hard to replicate what Java as without a GC.

Comment: @marathon Seems like the project was pretty much shut down since I looked at it years ago.. [sadly](http://code.google.com/p/nbds/). Ought to look into porting it sometime, there are actually some things you can do in C++ that you can't in Java (easily, without JNI obviously) which should really help with some problems in the Java design.. the lack of GC certainly makes all kind of high-performance concurrent algorithms interesting, but I have some ideas for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a *data race* on the `std::shared_ptr`, and the behaviour of programs with *data races* is undefined in C++.

The problem is: The class `std::shared_ptr` is not thread-safe. However, there are special atomic operations for `std::shared_ptr`, which can be used to solve the problem.

You can find more information about these atomic operations on the following webpage:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: That looks good, but std::atomic_is_lock_free(&fspReadMapReference) is returning "false" on my platform (macosx mavericks and CentOS).   Am I out of luck?

Comment: @marathon Assuming that you have an efficient CAS or ll/sc intrinsic on your platform (pretty much every architecture except µcs, etc. has one these days) you could implement it yourself. C++11 provides `atomic_compare_exchange` although there's nothing in the standard that prohibits it from being non lock-free (but that'd be rather horrible really).

Answer (score 1):

Reader should do two operations: get and put.  get always retrieves the new pointer and increments an atomic count.  Put releases the pointer and decrements.  Delete the map when the count goes to zero.
The writer creates a new map and does a get on it.  It then does a put on the old map to mark it for delete.